# backdrop-filter not working on iOS / effecting positioning?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have two weird issues with the CSS "backdrop-filter".

First, I use this snippet to create this frosted glass effect:

```
    webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px) saturate(100%) contrast(60%) brightness(130%);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px) saturate(100%) contrast(60%) brightness(130%);
```

It works great on all devices but my old iPad (6 Gen / iOS 14.7.1). There it just does not show up at all. It does work on other pages though ([here](https://daily-dev-tips.com/posts/css-frosted-glass-credit-card/) for example).
I guess some other file has to interfere then?
The website I try to achieve this is [here](https://dreschers.net/wpgo/)

The second issue is really weird. I use a dark mode with a separare stylesheet. For now the only difference in this stylesheet is a "backdrop-filter" for the body:

```
body {
    background-image: url(https://dreschers.net/wpgo/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Verlaeufe2.svg);
    backdrop-filter: grayscale(0.8);
}
```

But this filter does not apply to the whole body, only parts of it, and when I am logged into wordpress, it moves the adminbar. I just have no idea whatsoever why this happens.

[image: with light mode]

[image: with dark mode]

Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting hyphen is missing your in `-webkit-`:

```
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px) saturate(100%) contrast(60%) brightness(130%);
```

Comment: That actually fixed it, thank you.
Still having the second issue though

Comment: second issue: try body{min-height: 100vh}

Comment: it kind of works, at least for users it looks like it should. Logged in the adminbar is still not on top of the window. Tried top:0; and margin-top:0; for body and html, with no change. But its alright like this, thank you : )