# position: fixed; not working when backdrop-filter is used

Tags: css, webkit, css-position

As it can be seen in the snippet below, `position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;` doesn't work when the parent has a `backdrop-filter`.

Why?

Notes:

- A solution seems to be: prefix `backdrop-filter` with `-webkit-` as seen in [backdrop-filter not working on iOS / effecting positioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68811884/backdrop-filter-not-working-on-ios-effecting-positioning).
- But changing from `backdrop-filter` to `-webkit-backdrop-filter` has other slight differences that break my previous code (the overlay between div is slightly different).

Question:
**How to make `position: fixed;` work as usual even if `backdrop-filter` (and not `-webkit-backdrop-filter`) is used?**

```css
div { border: 1px solid black; }
.container { display: flex; }
.box1 { padding: 1rem; display: flex; }
.box2 { padding: 1rem; display: flex; backdrop-filter: blur(3px); }
.item { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box1">
        box1
        <div class="item">
            top-left item1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
        box2
        <div class="item">
            top-left item2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter forms a containing-block for its child (item2).

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#identifying_the_containing_block)

Whether -webkit- makes any difference sounds irrelevant in the general (ie any browser) case.

The only way forward I can immediately think of is to put whatever effect(s) you want into a before pseudo element and apply filter to the pseudo element only.

Comment: Would you have a snippet example with your pseudo element? I'm curious how it works. Thanks!

Comment: I don’t know what effect you want. Could you expand your code to show it?